# which position is self in python class?

Tags: python, class

In the book `learning python 5th edition (o'reilly  Mark Lutz)page912)`

```
class PrivateExc(Exception): pass                   # More on exceptions in Part VII
class Privacy:
    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):         # On self.attrname = value
        if attrname in self.privates:
            raise PrivateExc(attrname, self)        # Make, raise user-define except
        else:
            self.__dict__[attrname] = value         # Avoid loops by using dict key
class Test1(Privacy):
    privates = ['age']
class Test2(Privacy):
    privates = ['name', 'pay']
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['name'] = 'Tom'               # To do better, see Chapter 39!
```

Maybe it is wrong in the  5th line`raise PrivateExc(attrname, self)` ,
the self argument will be set as position 1st.
Will be the line changed into `raise PrivateExc(self,attrname)`?Why not?

Comment: There are no strict rules about args in user-defined exceptions. As long as the catching code is aware of the exception args meaning, it's fine.

Comment: I think that what confuses you is that every class function is defined with `self` as the first argument but this is not the case here: a) this is not a definition of a class method and b) the instance sends itself as an argument to the exception (that will probably be fully implemented in "Part VII")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just confused about parameters in function definition and function calling.

In a class, a method(instance method) has a non-optional parameter in the first position, usually named `self`, in the definition, like this:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, another_param): 
        pass
```

And the `self` references the instance that you call `foo` function with. If you have code like this:

```
f=Foo()
f.foo("test")
```

`self` references the `f` and `another_param` references the `"test"` string in the above code.

And then in the `foo` function, you can use `self` just like other parameters.

Suppose you have a `Print` function like this:

```
def Print(x):
    print "Param:", x
```

Then you can make you `Foo` class like this:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, another_param): 
        Print(another_param)  # I think this will not confuse you
```

Or this:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, another_param): 
        Print(self)  # Now, you may understand this, self is just a param in function calling, like another_param
```

And now, change the `Print` function to `PrivateExc`(you can think it a function to create a PrivateExc instance here), you may understand it either.

Hope these examples can help you understand you question.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it doesn't matter.

Subclassing from `Exception` without any additional constructor doesn't restrict what you can pass as arguments to the exception class. And you can pass them in any order you want.

The arguments passed to the `PrivateExc` class just get stored in the instance as the instance attribute `.args`

**Example:**

```
>>> class MyError(Exception):
...     """MyError"""
... 
>>> e = MyError("foo", "bar")
>>> e.args
('foo', 'bar')
>>> e
MyError('foo', 'bar')
```

What this basically means in the book you're reading is;

If you were to catch the exception `PrivateExc` you'd do something like this:

```
try:
    ...
except PrivateExc as error:
   attrname, obj = error.args
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling a method like this:

```
#!/bin/python
myinstance.some_method(a,b,c)
```

... then this is dispatched to `some_method` as: `some_method(myinstance, a, b, c)`

The instance through which the method was invoked is passed as your first argument.  This is completely different than C++ and Java ... which use an implicit "this" reference ... a pointer valid from within your method's scope but not passed to it as an argument.

I hope that answers your question, thought the code example does nothing to clarify what you're attempting to do.